# Bootstrap close responsive menu "on click"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On "PRODUCTS" click I slide up a white div (as seen in attached).  When in responsive (mobile and tablet), I would like to automaticly close the responsive navbar and only show the white bar.

I tried:

```
$('.btn-navbar').click();
```

also tried:

```
$('.nav-collapse').toggle();
```

And it does work. However in desktop size, it is also called and does something funky to the menu where it shrinks for a second.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you post some HTML? Also are you using Bootstrap for the hide functionality? Or are you trying to implement something of your own?

Comment: I'm just trying to do something simple, I think.  I just want to close the navbar when I click on "PRODUCTS"

Comment: If you don't want to try and compare all these solutions here yourself, [edit #1 from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23171593/89818) is what you should do.

Comment: I recomend scrolling a bit down here and look @LukeTillman answer. Works perfectly and without jQuery. :)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I've got it to work with animation!

Menu in html:

```
<div id="nav-main" class="nav-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav">
         <li>
             <a href='#somewhere'>Somewhere</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Binding click event on all a elements in navigation to collapse menu (Bootstrap collapse plugin):

```
 $(function(){ 
     var navMain = $("#nav-main");
     navMain.on("click", "a", null, function () {
         navMain.collapse('hide');
     });
 });
```

**EDIT**
To make it more generic we can use following code snippet

```
 $(function(){ 
     var navMain = $(".navbar-collapse"); // avoid dependency on #id
     // "a:not([data-toggle])" - to avoid issues caused
     // when you have dropdown inside navbar
     navMain.on("click", "a:not([data-toggle])", null, function () {
         navMain.collapse('hide');
     });
 });
```

Comment: If not all `a` elements: you just need is to call `$("#nav-main").collapse('hide');`

Comment: @mollwe Do you have a solution for when it has a dropdown menu? I made a jsfiddle to try but even the menu won't open. http://jsfiddle.net/Y3H92/

Comment: @clankill3r there seems to me that a reference to bootstrap.js is missing and therefore the menu won't work. I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3H92/1/

Comment: @mollwe with your fiddle the menu won't close at all for me.

Comment: Sorry for late response @clankill3r! But better late than never. http://jsfiddle.net/mollwe/Y3H92/5/

Comment: @mollwe It causes issue if you have dropdown inside navbar. To avoid that we need to use `navMain.on("click", "a:not([data-toggle])", null, function () {`. This way the click handler will execute only on links that don't have `data-toggle` attribute i.e. links that are not dropdowns. Also to make it generic its better to use `var navMain = $(".navbar-collapse");`. I'm updating the answer accordingly (hope you don't mind).

Comment: you don't need `null` argument in `on("click", "a", null,`

Answer (score 145):

You don't have to add any extra javascript to what's already included with bootstraps collapse option.  Instead simply include data-toggle and data-target selectors on your menu list items just as you do with your navbar-toggle button.  So for your Products menu item it would look like this

```
<li><a href="#Products" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Products</a></li>
```

Then you would need to repeat the data-toggle and data-target selectors for each menu item

**EDIT!!!**
In order to fix overflow issues and flickering on this fix I'm adding some more code that will fix this and still not have any extra javascript.  Here is the new code:

```
<li><a href="#products" class="hidden-xs">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#products" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Products</a></li>
```

Here it is at work http://jsfiddle.net/jaketaylor/84mqazgq/

This will make your toggle and target selectors specific to screen size and eliminate glitches on the larger menu.  If anyone is still having issues with glitches please let me know and I'll find a fix.
Thanks

**EDIT**: In the bootstrap v4.1.3 & v5.0 I couldnt use visible/hidden classes. Instead of `hidden-xs` use `d-none d-sm-block` and instead of `visible-xs` use `d-block d-sm-none`.

**EDIT**: In bootstrap v5, Instead of `data-toggle` use `data-bs-toggle` and instead of `data-target` use `data-bs-target`.

Comment: that causes flickering and weird stuff when the nav is not displayed as the "responsive" menu.

Comment: i removed my downvote on this answer and my previous comment (also since the video was not working anymore). since my comment about flickering is still valid for the original answer, got a few upvotes and your "edit" is clearly marked i don't see a reason to remove it and rewrite history. it was valid at the time and you reacted accordingly. people reading your answer will see the "edit" and know you improved on it...

Comment: You prefer duplicating all your links just to avoid a single line of perfectly documented javascript? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods.

Comment: @Sander Garretsen  Is this a real question?  All you did was reference to bootstrap's js collapse methods.  Did you have an answer for the original question?  If so you can post it at the bottom of the page :)

Comment: This is really good solution, but duplicating navigational links is not a good idea. For me the version before edition and enhanced by @luketillman worked fine and gives pretty clean and logical markup + no additional js needed.

Comment: the trick visible-xs is not necessary. just replace .navbar-collapse by .navbar-collapse.in and it works fine on mobile and desktop

Comment: @TMMC & amdev The problem with the .in class being added is that for some reason it causes issues with several other plugins such as scrollspy and supermenu.  If you don't plan on using any extensions/plugins outside of bootstrap then this method is fine.  Also, if duplicating navigational links was such a bad idea then I doubt sites like paypal would be doing it...which they are :) I'd love to see your documentation on why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @jake-taylor, well I do not mean to argue, the simplest answer is 'because it is', the more complex one is because it is illogical and misleading for those who use screen readers - no documentation is needed for it I hope :) BTW sites like Paypal doesn't really give a **** about anything but money ;)

Comment: @TMMC So obviously the developers of Paypal aren't nearly as knowledgeable as you ;)

Comment: @jake-taylor, I would rather say - they do not care ;)

Comment: Instead of adding the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes to every li element you can instead add it to the parent `ul` or `div` tags.

Comment: @jrquick  This is true..but much like my original answer, you still get the glitches on larger screen sizes when clicking on links with this method.  If you've found a way to eliminate this, then post a fiddle and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is causing flickering in desktop screens.

Comment: Using this on Blazor WASM it does collapse the menu but does not navigate anymore.

Answer (score 41):

I think you are all over engineering..

```
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function(){ 
            $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });
```

EDIT: To take care of sub menus, make sure their toggle anchor has the dropdown-toggle class on it.

```
    $(function () { 
            $('.navbar-collapse ul li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function () { 
                    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click(); 
            }); 
    });
```

EDIT 2: Add support for phone touch.

```
    $(function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse ul li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').bind('click touchstart', function () {
                    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
            });
    });
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. The others _are_ over-engineered and flicker on the non-responsive display.

Comment: This could be the accepted answer but it doesn't take into account sub menus and in fact breaks them. Some of the other "over engineered" solutions did take this into account, despite their short-comings. The following addition would take care of this:

$(function () {
  $('.navbar-collapse ul li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
  });
});

Comment: I think touchstart is a bit to much, click works fine. how does it respond to sliding when you "start" from the button?

Comment: This was perfect, thank you! I've made it into a pure vanilla js function which I added to the the click event.
`const closeMenu=e=>{if(document.getElementById(e).classList.contains("show")){document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-toggler")[0].click()}};
`

Answer (score 40):

I really liked Jake Taylor's idea of doing it without additional JavaScript and taking advantage of Bootstrap's collapse toggle.  I found you can fix the "flickering" issue present when the menu isn't in collapsed mode by modifying the `data-target` selector slightly to include the `in` class.  So it looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#Products" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Products</a></li>
```

I didn't test it with nested dropdowns/menus, so YMMV.

Comment: This was the best implementation for me as well.

Comment: For some reason my ScrollSpy breaks with this method, but works fine with Jake Taylor's method.

Comment: The best and simplest answer so far.

Comment: Been trying to get a non-flicker collapse to work for a while, but this is by far the most simple and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

just to be complete, in Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta using *.show* worked for me...

```
<li>
  <a href="#Products" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Products</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you have a line like this defining the nav area, based on Bootstrap examples and all

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" >
```

Simply add the properties as such, like on the MENU button

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

I've added to `<body>` as well, worked.  Can't say I've profiled it or anything, but seems a treat to me...until you click on a random spot of the UI to open the menu, so not so good that.

DK

Comment: Proper solution relying on Bootstrap's built-in functionality; no additional jQuery or javascript. And the simplest solution of all. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This works, but does not animate.

```
$('.btn-navbar').addClass('collapsed');
$('.nav-collapse').removeClass('in').css('height', '0');
```

Comment: It's a bit surprising that there is not a config option for this as close on click would be a better default.

Answer (score 3):

In the HTML I added a class of **nav-link** to the **a** tag of each navigation link.

```
$('.nav-link').click(
    function () {
        $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

this solution have a fine work, on desktop and mobile.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Comment: worked for me when using the navbar-id as data-target: <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#navbar"> but gives an ugly animation while in desktop-size

Answer (score 2):

Just to spell out user1040259's solution, add this code to your $(document).ready(function() {});

```
    $('.nav').click( function() {
        $('.btn-navbar').addClass('collapsed');
        $('.nav-collapse').removeClass('in').css('height', '0');
    });
```

As they mention, this doesn't animate the move... but it does close the nav bar on item selection

Answer (score 2):

For those using AngularJS and Angular UI Router with this, here is my solution (using mollwe's toggle).
Where ".navbar-main-collapse" is my "data-target".

Create directive:

```
module.directive('navbarMainCollapse', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            //watch for state/route change (Angular UI Router specific)
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
                if (!element.hasClass('collapse')) {
                    element.collapse('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Use Directive:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
    <your menu>
```

Comment: Looks like you put the directive in the class attr, is that right?

Comment: Inside the link function the following should work.
    
    element.on('click', function () {
        scope.vm.isCollapsed = !scope.vm.isCollapsed;
    });

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

Requires bootstrap.js.

Example => http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

```
    $('.nav li a').click(function() {
      $('#nav-main').collapse('hide');
    });
```

This does the same thing as adding 'data-toggle="collapse"' and 'href="yournavigationID"' attributes to navigation menus  tags.

Comment: Could you explain the answer in a bit more detail?

Comment: Isn't that jQuery? Isn't it generally bad practice to use both jQuery and Angular?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 solution without any Javascript

Add attributes `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent.show"`  to the div `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">`

Make sure you provide the correct `id` in `data-target`

```
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent.show">
```

> `.show` is to avoid menu flickering in large resolutions

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent.show">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy solution for this. Just add the toggle code of the button on the navbar links too.
In the below example is the code `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"`.

This will close the menu when clicked and follow the link

```
    <!--data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" from toggle button --> 
           <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-format-mobile" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"> <!--https://stackoverflow.com/a/65365121/5763690-->
                <li class="nav-item">

<!--data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" from toggle button to nav item --> 
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" [routerLink]="'about'" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Services
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="'services'" fragment="why-us" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="'services'" fragment="project" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">For companies</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="'services'" fragment="startups" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">For Startups</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="'/services'" fragment="ngos" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">For NGOs</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
<!--data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" from toggle button to nav item --> 
                  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="'products'" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="'career'" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">Career</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="'contact'" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: This works for Angular 13 and Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the mollwe function, although I added 2 improvements:

a) Avoid the dropdown closing if the link clicked is collapsed (including other links)

b) Hide the dropdown too, if you are clicking the visible web content.

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function() {
                  return this.length > 0;
              }

    $(function() {
                var navMain = $(".navbar-collapse");
                navMain.on("click", "a", null, function() {
                    if ($(this).attr("href") !== "#") {
                        navMain.collapse('hide');
                    }
                });

                $("#content").bind("click", function() {
                     if ($(".navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse.in").exists()) {
                        navMain.collapse('hide');
                    }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the newest thread but i searched for a solution for the same Problem and found one (a mix of some others).

I gave the NavButton:

```
<type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> ...
```

an id / Identifier like:

```
 <button id="navcop" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

Not the finest "Idea" - but: Works for me!
Now you can check up the visibility of your button (with jquery) like:

```
 var target = $('#navcop');
   if(target.is(":visible")){
   $('#navcop').click();
   }
```

(NOTE: This is just a Code snipped ! I used a "onclick" Event on my Nav Links! (Starting a AJAX Reguest.)

The result is: If the Button is "visible" it got "clicked" ... So: No Bug if you use the "Fullscreen view" of Bootstrap (width of over 940px).

Greetings
Ralph

PS: It works fine with IE9, IE10 and Firefox 25. Didnt checked up others - But i can't see a Problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I have done like, when i click on the menu button, im adding or removing the class 'in' because by adding or removing that class the toggle is working by default. 'e.stopPropagation()' is to stop the default animation by bootstrap(i guess) you can also use the 'toggleClass' in place of add or remove class.

$('#ChangeToggle').on('click', function (e) {

```
        if ($('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
            $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            $('.navbar-collapse').addClass('in');
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cau use

```
ul.nav {
    display: none;
}
```

This will by default close the navbar.
Please let me know anybody finds this usefull

Comment: problem is, this hides the nav when displayed "normally", not in the responsive menu.

Answer (score 0):

If for example your toggle-able icon is visible only for extra small devices, then you could do something like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('#side-menu').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
});
```

Clicking [data-toggle="offcanvas"] will add bootstrap's .hidden-xs to my #side-menu which will hide the side-menu content, but will become visible again if you increase the window size.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navbar-toggle').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the right answer? whenever you click any of the menu link on that click event you can toggle menu which I think is the right way because I'm not changing the default behaviour of opening or closing menu.

Answer (score 0):

if menu html is

```
<div id="nav-main" class="nav-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav">
         <li>
             <a href='#somewhere'>Somewhere</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

on nav toggle 'in' class is added and removed from the toggle. check if responsive menu is opened then perform the close toggle.

```
$('.nav-collapse .nav a').on('click', function(){
    if ( $( '.nav-collapse' ).hasClass('in') ) {
        $('.navbar-toggle').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuggle Nav Close, IE browser compatible answer, without any console error.
If you are using bootstrap, use this

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function () {
    if ($("#navbar").hasClass("in")) {
        $('.navbar-collapse.in').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.navbar-collapse.in').hide();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other suggestions in my Vue.js 3 app, however my vue-router router-links wouldn't work anymore.

I created a small function to click the menu toggle, if the menu had the "show" class. This worked great for me in all cases.

```
<template>
...
<div
    id="navbarNavigation"
    class="collapse navbar-collapse"
  >
    <ul
      class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"
    >
      <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link
          :to="route.url"
          class="nav-link"
          @click="closeMenu('navbarNavigation')"
        >
          My route name
        </router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
...
</template>

<script>
setup (props) {
    const closeMenu = (id) => {
      const menuShown = document.getElementById(id).classList.contains('show')
      if (menuShown) {
        const menuToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggler')[0]
        menuToggle.click()
      }
    }

    return { closeMenu }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For peeps looking for a solution concerning **Vue 3 `router-link`** with **Bootstrap 5** + **`data-bs`-attributes**:

Using `data-bs`-attributes to toggle the nav directly on a Vue-`router-link` doesn't seem to work - so instead you need to wrap each of your nav-links in a parent element if not already done (an `li` would be the obvious choice) and apply the relevant `data-bs`-attributes on that element.

In short - instead of this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <router-link
    to="/galaxy"
    class="nav-link d-flex"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse.show"
  >
    <v-icon name="gi-galaxy" size="1" class="align-middle" scale="1.5" />
    <span class="flex-fill align-middle text-start ms-3 ms-lg-1">The Galaxy</span>
  </router-link>
</li>
```

Use this:

```
<li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse.show">
  <router-link to="/galaxy" class="nav-link d-flex">
    <v-icon name="gi-galaxy" class="align-middle" scale="1.5" />
    <span class="flex-fill align-middle text-start ms-3 ms-lg-1">The Galaxy</span>
  </router-link>
</li>
```