# Bootstrap 3 Navbar won't Collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Please watch the video as I go through the problem I’m having. The navbar won’t collapse when I select the link in mobile view.

Video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dBpcFMjqY0

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to add links to my code.

Comment: @KenY-N http://codepen.io/rawadm/pen/waBpye

Comment: see on the portfolio it collapse as soon as you select a link? I apologies if my explanation wasn't the best.http://rawadmerhi.com/

Comment: change it to mobile view and select a link you will see the navbar collapsing.

Comment: Ahh, I finally see what you mean; however, this [appears to be a feature](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12852).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click), and playing about with your fiddle, the following seems to fix the problem:

```
<li class="current"><a href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Home </a></li>
<li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Contact</a></li>
```

See the [updated fiddle here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYRXz).

Comment: @Thanks, you mentioned that .navbar-collapse.in  is a feature in Bootstrap?@Ken Y-N