# Angular with bootstrap: How to toggle up the nav bar in responsive mood?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `angularJS` and `bootstrap` in a single project.

When the web page is in the **responsive mood** , bootstrap navbar menu changes to toggler the menu responsive nav bar.

The issue is when I use angular routing and menu toggle down. After clicking in one of the links of menu, **it doesn't toggle up** because of not refreshing the page.

Any idea?

Nav bar code :

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggle"
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target=".navbar-collapse"
      >
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="navCtrl">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a>Modal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click might be what you are looking for (especially 2nd answer without using javascript).

Comment: do you have angular-ui-bootstrap in your project?

Comment: @BillCheng Thanks. It was exactly what I need.

Comment: @wickY26 No, I don't, but I'm going to search about it. Thank you.