# Menu doesn't collapse after clicking, Storefront theme wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, storefront

I'm using the Storefront theme in wordpress and I have a problem with the menu on the mobile site. 
After clicking a menu item, the menu should collapse. I've looked online, but there is a lot of Javacode for the Bootstrap plugin, and I cannot get this working with the Storefront theme.

[Website](http://www.yaribu.com/blanco2)

[Bootstrap close responsive menu "on click"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click)

Comment: `$('.handheld navigation a').on('click', function(){ $('menu-toggle').click()});` something like this I have