# toggleClass from within the fully outed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can't seem to make it work. when i click on the menu icon, the menu comes out ok
and it closes when i click again.
but how do i toggle when i click and a url within the menu itself?
I tried adding a class to each li and adding the clas on the function i tried meny thing. maybe its because i have angular on the li?

```
<div class="icomMenu"></div>
<navbar class="">
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="index" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="About" ui-sref-active="active">About</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="Contact" ui-sref-active="active">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="Nested" ui-sref-active="active">Nested</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</navbar>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".icomMenu").click(function() {
        $("navbar").toggleClass("NavOut");
    });
});
```

[image]

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap close responsive menu "on click"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click)

Comment: Thank you Michelangelo. "Binding click event on all a elements in navigation to collapse menu" did the trick. changing my advanced nested stateProvider to just state was to overkill for something the binding solve.

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you are using angular I would recommend going against using jQuery and instead using component/view controller to handle this. You can for example add `ng-class="{'NavOut': vm.menuVisible}"` to your `navbar` HTML element and then instead of using `ui-sref` on the li elements you can use `ng-click="vm.onMenuItemClick("About")"` then in controller you can inject `$state` and create method `onMenuItemClick(link)` that will set `this.menuVisible = false` and go to another route with `this.$state.go(link)`.

EDIT:
Template:
`<div class="icomMenu"></div>
<navbar ng-class="{'NavOut: vm.menuVisible}">
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-click="vm.onMenuClick('Home')" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</navbar>`

Controller:

```
constructor($state) {
  this.$state = $state;
}

this.onMenuClick(link) {
  this.$state.go(link);
  this.menuVisible = false;
}
```

Something like that, I hope you get the idea. The navbar seems like the ideal candidate for creating an component then use it's controller to handle the logic above.

Comment: Maksym , I tried messing up with angular and am using $stateProvider which i think its the same method as $state but you put too much information here and is not clear to me. its not you but cumbersome thank  you anyways.

Comment: @l3ny Updated the answer, hopefully you'll understand it :)