# Making menu disappear on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

So I have bootstrap menu that is one my one page site and its really good but it has one issue.

When on a mobile viewpoint and you click on the hamburger it launches the side panel, when a user clicks on a link (anchor link in my case to a section on the page) it will take you to the anchor but the side panel remains in position. I want it so that when the link is clicked the side panel disappears from view.

I have tried to look for solutions but to no success, I think it doesn't work because the solution depends on how the menu was made so if anyone can help me out here it would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="site-mobile-menu site-navbar-target">
  <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
    <div class="site-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
      <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
</div>


<header class="site-navbar js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">

      <div class="col-6 col-xl-2">
        <h1 class="mb-0 site-logo"><a href="index.html">Brand<span class="text-primary">. 
                     </span> </a></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-none d-xl-block">
        <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">

          <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
            <li><a href="#home-section" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="has-children">
              <a href="#about-section" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#team-section" class="nav-link">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing-section" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#faq-section" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery-section" class="nav-link">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services-section" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials-section" class="nav-link">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a href="#">More Links</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#blog-section" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="social"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span 
                            class="icon- 
                         facebook"></span></a></li>
            <li class="social"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span 
                      class="icon- 
                          twitter"></span></a></li>
            <li class="social"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span 

                     class="icon-linkedin"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6 d-inline-block d-xl-none ml-md-0 py-3" style="position: relative; top: 
                `3px;"><a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle float-right"><span 
                  class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>`

    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please revise the snippet I created to add your libraries via CDN. This will result in a functional demonstration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap close responsive menu "on click"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click)

Comment: Thanks for the link Ghost, I tried using that but it collapse the menu but I could not get it to open again, when I tried to open again it added overlay to my screen but the panel wasnt there.