# Bootstrap 5 Navbar menu link not working when added 'data-bs-toggle' and 'data-bs-target'

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I followed this post as for close responsive menu "on click":

[Bootstrap close responsive menu "on click"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click)

But when I click on menu i.e. link it **doesn't goes/move to intended div on page.**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navigation-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="60" alt=""> पोटोबा</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="fas fa-stream navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a>
          <!-- added additional attributes to links data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse"  -->

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#about" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#explore-food">Explore Food</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#testimonial">Reviews</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#faq">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li><button class="main-btn">1700 345 123</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Those attributes are for manipulating accordions. They probably disable link functionality intentionally. Do you have collapsible elements in the page?

Answer (score 0):

check which version you are using of bootstrap `data-bs-toggle` is for bootstrap 5, if you are using bootstrap 4 the data attributes are different something like `data-toggle` and `data-target`