# How do I get the navigation to collapse att predefined size into the small icon for mobile devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

based on [How do I get the navigation to collapse into the small icon for mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150423/how-do-i-get-the-navigation-to-collapse-into-the-small-icon-for-mobile-devices)
i want to let the navigation collapse, but not at the 970px size but rather at a predefined size - let's say 300px. is it possible within bootstrap or do i have to tweek it myself?

my current code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href="/">name</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#price">Price</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you want it fixed at 970px ? and only be responsive at 300px

Comment: @Shail yes, i want i to be fixed when the width of the browser is >300px; otherwise i want it to collapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the media queries within the CSS.  Locate the media query that is forcing the collapse, cut it and create your own query with 300px.  Like:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
.nav-collapse {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: there are seferal `@media` queries, although only one with `translate3d`. changing this part had no effect at all. any clue where to make changes in the general `bootstrap-responsive.css` file?

Comment: found it: i had to delete all `.nav-collapse` definition within all other @media, such as `@media (max-width: 979px)`, too. than the easiest way was to go custom like @Shail above said and generate my own collapse part

Answer (score 1):

YOu can go to customize bootstrap at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and than deselect the responsive feature you dont need from The **Responsive** section .

Than write media queries if necessary to arrange stuff .Also you can set  min-width to an element to stop it from resizing .

Comment: @ulkas you dont have to manually delete ... thats wat I was suggesting .. anyway .